# Autofac registration resolved by method

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm using [CacheManager](https://github.com/MichaCo/CacheManager) and it uses a factory to create instances. I don't want to have to register every type of ICacheManager that I declare so I'm looking for a way to register the generic type with a dynamic resolve method. Using Ninject, I could do this:

```
kernel
    .Bind(typeof(ICacheManager<>))
    .ToMethod((context) => CacheFactory.FromConfiguration(context.GenericArguments[0], "defaultCache"))
    .InSingletonScope();
```

where context.GenericArguments[0] would be the type of my generic. For example, object from

```
ICacheManager<object> cache;
```

How do I do something like this using Autofac?

**Edit**

Working IRegistrationSource based on Cyril's answer below. SingleInstance is required since CacheManager prepends keys with the CacheManager instance id.

```
public class CacheManagerRegistrationSource : IRegistrationSource
{
    public Boolean IsAdapterForIndividualComponents
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(Service service, Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
    {
        IServiceWithType typedService = service as IServiceWithType;
        if (typedService == null || !typedService.ServiceType.IsGenericType)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        Type cacheManagerType = typedService.ServiceType;
        if (cacheManagerType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(ICacheManager<>))
        {
            yield break; 
        }

        IComponentRegistration registration = (IComponentRegistration)RegistrationBuilder.ForDelegate(cacheManagerType, (c, p) =>
        {
            return CacheFactory.FromConfiguration(cacheManagerType.GetGenericArguments()[0], "defaultCache");
        })
        .SingleInstance()
        .CreateRegistration();

        yield return registration;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default *Autofac* doesn't allow to retrieve the generic type of object being registered. There is no easy built-in way to do this but you can use a `IRegistrationSource` to achieve what you want :

```
public class CacheManagerRegistrationSource : IRegistrationSource
{
    public Boolean IsAdapterForIndividualComponents
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(Service service, Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
    {
        IServiceWithType typedService = service as IServiceWithType;
        if (typedService == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        Type cacheManagerType = typedService.ServiceType
                                            .GetInterfaces()
                                            .Where(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICacheManager<>))
                                            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (cacheManagerType == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        IComponentRegistration registration =
            RegistrationBuilder.ForDelegate(cacheManagerType, (c, p) => {
                return CacheFactory.FromConfiguration(cacheManagerType.GetGenericArguments()[0], "defaultCache");
            })
            .SingleInstance()
            .CreateRegistration();

        yield return registration;
    }
}
```

then you will have to register the registration source by doing :

```
builder.RegisterSource(new CacheManagerRegistrationSource());
```

This is the way the `RegisterGeneric` method works internally.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was almost spot on. I've posted the working code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

It's awful, but you can do the following:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(ICacheManager<>))
    .OnActivating(e =>
    {
        var instance = typeof(CacheFactory).GetMethod("FromConfiguration").MakeGenericMethod
            e.Instance.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0])
            .Invoke(null, new object[] { "..." });
        e.ReplaceInstance(instance);
    });
```

Comment: When I try that I get this error message: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Autofac.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The type 'CacheManager.Core.ICacheManager`1' does not implement the interface 'CacheManager.Core.ICacheManager`1'.

Comment: Ohh, I see why. I accidentally tested this code with the following mock declaration `public class ICacheManager<T> { }`. Note, it is not an interface, but a class.

Comment: It's bad solution. Every time you will create two instance - first instance by default and second instance is your new instance.